# How do you find a Quire task's parent task using the API?

Tags: quire-api

Is there a way (other than doing a tree search using the '/tasks' API starting at the project root) to find the parent task of any subtask using the Quire API?

Answer (score 1):

currently there's no such feature, so I posted the [FR #42](https://github.com/quire-api/quire-api/issues/42)
please watch/comment/correct/upvote the [FR #42](https://github.com/quire-api/quire-api/issues/42) on github.